# Get the even digit in a number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evenDigits1(int num);

int main() {
    int number;
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("EvenDigits(): %d\n", evenDigits1(number));
    return 0;
}

int evenDigits1(int num) {
    int x, result, i = 1;
    float evenNum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        x = num % 10;
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            evenNum += x;
            evenNum /= 10;
            i *= 10;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    result = evenNum * i;
    if (result == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Why is it when I enter `4488` or `1144889`, it will display `4487` instead of `4488`? For other number such as `44488` or `123456`, it will show correctly (`44488` and `246`).

How do I display `4488` as `4488` instead of `4487`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like a perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Why do you define `evenNum` as a floating pointer number? This is actually a big hint to your problem...

Comment: What should I define my evenNum? I define it as floating pointer because of decimal.

Comment: Why? You initialize it to an integer value. You add an integer value. You divide an integer value to get an integer value result (and here things will start to go wrong) and you multiply by an integer.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this? Can I add .0 behind the integer value to make it a float? Or how should I proceed. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: You don't *need* decimals here, only integers. So make `evenNum` an `int` and you won't have the rounding errors that comes with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: But I will get 0 since evenNum / 10 will be 0.4 if my evenNum is 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207111/discussion-between-barnacle-own-and-some-programmer-dude).